# How to solve a conflict between a local app named 'social' and 'python-social-auth' in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have a Django Application in which I wanted to include social logins so I decided to choose 'python-social-auth' for that purpose but the problem is that when I include `social.apps.django_app.default` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and run `./manage.py makemigrations` I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named apps.django_app
```

The reason for this is, I guess, that I have an app named 'social' in my `INSTALLED_APPS` so when django start reads through this tuple it conflicts the `social` in the beginning of `social.apps.django_app.default` with the `social` app.

I hope I could make you understand my point. If I did please help me out in solving this problem. :)

**Edit:**

Here is a snippet from `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social',
    ...
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)
```

As the first answer suggests I can change the refer to the app with a different name. Now the problem is that I can change the `'social'` to something else using `AppConfig`, but again when the interpreter tries to read `'social.apps.django_app.default`' it looks in the local app folder named `social`. How can I make it look into the distribution files that reside in my `python2.7/site-packages` folder?

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.7, there is [App Config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#for-application-users), which allows you to change the name with which you refer to an app in INSTALLED_APPS, allowing you to avoid name conflicts.

Comment: My app was created in django 1.6. Can I do that in 1.6?

Comment: No, because App Config was not introduced until Django 1.7. You need to upgrade your Django version to use App Config.

Comment: Please have a look at the question. I've updated it.